# Обучающийся - да! Обучающий - нет?

Tags: лексика

Есть хорошее русское слово *ученик*. Его значение всем понятно. Но кому-то оно показалось недостаточным для обозначения человека учащегося (в слове *ученик* нет значения действия) и его заменили причастием *учащийся*. Но спустя некоторое время опять кому-то показалось мало, что человек просто учится, он должен ещё чему-то научиться (или обучиться). Так *ученик* стал *обучающимся*. Оставим эти преобразования на совести чиновников. Но меня интересует другое: почему при этом так "несправедливо" обошлись с *учителем*, который не превратился ни в *учащего* ни в *обучающего*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Наверное, потому, что учитель, по большому счету, чиновникам не интересен! Ведь он всего лишь (снова с их легкой руки) предоставляет образовательные услуги. Слава Богу, что хоть слово учитель не пострадало.
Вопрос интересный с точки зрения связи языка (не только лексики. но и грамматики)с философией народа, его мировоззрением, духовными традициями. Просьба к участникам форума, если встречали статьи по этой теме, дайте ссылку, пожалуйста. Можно на e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Сслылок нет, может найду что-нибудь. А пока, если позволите, своими словами.

В замене "ученика" на "учащегося" есть определённый смысл. Всё-таки не всякий ученик - учащийся и наоборот. Школе ближе именно учащийся. Автор несколько погорячился, говоря о "хорошем русском слове". В нынешнем значении оно появилось в связи с послереволюционным упразднением "гимназиста". До революции же было всё вполне понятно. Гимназисты (лицеисты и т.д.), учащиеся (ремесленных, в основном, училищ), школьники религиозных и т.п. школ (только не путать со "школьником" в школах при синагогах) и, наконец, собственно ученики-подмастерья, этих за "учащихся" не держали. И при этом в большинстве случаев преподаватель мог называться учителем, хотя обычно имел и официальное название в зависимости от типа заведения. Так что можно усмотреть даже некоторый возрат к истокам. В этом смысле и появление учащегося, и сохранение учителя оправдано.

Вот "обучающиеся" - это уже бред чиновников. По сути это синоним именно ученика, не учащегося. Т.е. вернулись к тому, от чего так страстно хотели уйти в 17-м, но при этом совершенно не понимая смысл термина.

Comment: Слово-то как раз хорошее русское. У Жуковского оно в самом высоком своём значении:"Победителю-ученику от побеждённого учителя". Да, в советское время ученик и школьник стали синонимами, но это не повод заменять "ученик" на канцелярское "учащийся". В обоих случаях ("учащийся" и "обучающийся") я вижу только чиновничье стремление к словотворчеству.  А вот почему "учителя" не тронули, я так и не поняла.

Comment: Учителей называли шкрабами в двадцатые годы) Преподаватели никуда не делись, педагоги...